# Efficient date comparison (DATE portion of DATETIME value within one month)

Tags: date, datetime, type-conversion, comparison, getdate

I need to check if the date portion of dd.eventduedate (a DATETIME value returned by a function) is upcoming within one month. The WHERE clause below works, but I'm concerned that it's inefficient due to the four CONVERT operations.  Is there a better (faster) way?

```
CONVERT(DATE, dd.eventduedate) >= CONVERT(DATE, getdate()) AND CONVERT(DATE, dd.eventduedate) <= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
```